# How to copy a specific row from one sheet to another (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

this is my first post, so forgive me if the question is not worded quite the way it is for the platform.

I'm currently working on a Google Apps script that is supposed to search a sheet (name: "[Overview] All Cases") and its rows for a certain value in column Y. This particular value is "No". If a row has this value, this row should be copied to the last row of another sheet ("OPS_FUNNEL").The row should then exist in both sheets.  Can anyone help?

I have been through countless threads and have not been able to gather a solution. My solution so far, which does not work, you can see here:

```
function copy_to_OPS_FUNNEL() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("[Overview] All_Cases");
  var tarSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OPS_FUNNEL_new");
  var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
  
  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {

    var cell = srcSheet.getRange("Y" + i);

    var val = cell.getValue();

    if (val == 'No') {
      
      var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("A" + i + ":B" + i);
      var sourcevalues = srcRange.getValues();
      
      var tarRow = tarSheet.getLastRow();
      var tarRange = tarSheet.getRange("A" + (tarRow + i) + ":B" + (tarRow + i));
      
      tarRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

      srcSheet.getRange("Y"+(i+0).toString()).setValue("Yes");

  }
  else{

  } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You have two goals:

1. Copy the rows in sheet `[Overview] All_Cases` that contain "No" in column **Y** to the `OPS_FUNNEL_new` sheet.
2. After the copy is done, change the "No" in sheet `[Overview] All_Cases` to "Yes".

Three major improvements:

- It is not recommended to iteratively call `getRange` and `setRange`, read [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) for more info.
- You don't need a for loop and if statements to find the data that contains "No" in column **Y**. Instead you [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) this data with one line of code:

  ```
  const data = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r=>r[24]=='No');
  ```
- Then, copy it to the target sheet with one line of code:

`tarSheet.getRange(tarSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);`

### Solution:

```
function copy_to_OPS_FUNNEL() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("[Overview] All_Cases");
  const tarSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OPS_FUNNEL_new");
  const data = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r=>r[24]=='No').map(r => [r[0]]);
  if (data.length>0){
    tarSheet.getRange(tarSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,1).setValues(data);
    srcSheet.getRange("Y2:Y"+srcSheet.getLastRow()).setValue("Yes");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!

It works almost perfectly. Is there another way to copy only the value from column A? Or from a specific range (for example: "A:T"). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user14523871 my question is what do you want? column "A" or range "A:T" ?

Comment: I want to copy only the value from column "A" from "Overview All_Cases" to "OPS_FUNNEL".

Comment: Could you please help me with one more little thing? How do I change your above solution if I want to copy the complete row with its values and formatting and paste it into my targetsheet? After copying I want to delete exactly the row from the sourceSheet. The condition for this is again that there is a 'No' in a column (for example T). Thank you very much!

Comment: @user14523871 Hi unfortunately stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions. Could you please post a new question regarding that modification. Sorry for the inconvenience. Feel free to provide the url of the new question here so I can find it faster.